# Ruby: serialport stops work after upload

Tags: ruby, arduino

I'm reading values from Arduino serial port, using serialport gem.

`serialport.readline` is showing EOFError (after a few readings, or none), as long as I don't reboot computer.
 Then it works perfectly, up to the time upload new program to arduino (using platformio, linux) or access this port by anythink else.

```
require 'gtk3'
require 'serialport'

serialline = nil

serial = Thread.new do
    serialport = SerialPort.new('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
    loop do
        serialline = serialport.readline
    end
end

gtk = Thread.new do

    #Some gtk here

    GLib::Timeout.add(10) do
        #some other gtk
        puts serialline
    end
end


gtk.join
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll solve your problem, but it seems like closing the port after you're done would be a good idea. Or you could use [`SerialPort.open`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/serialport/SerialPort#open-class_method) with a block instead of `SerialPort.new` to close it automatically (though I don't know how robust it is).

Comment: Are you certain the baud rate is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct and what I forgot to write is that in the same time, ruby serialport is not working, python with pyserial, and platformio serial monitor works.

Comment: What happens if you remove GTK and all the threading stuff? I.e., transform it into a command line tool?

Comment: Unfortunately still the same.

Comment: Are you running this program and the python program at the same time? They can't both open the serial port.

Comment: No, separetely. But if i run anythink which acces this serial port (so not only uploading breaks it), the ruby code don't work any more.